# Start date of new event follows start date of clicked event - fullCalendar

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am trying to do something where, when I click on an event, it places a new event on the calendar. This new event spans 1 hour, and has the same start date as the clicked event:

```
eventClick: function(event) {

    var startDate = event.start
    var endDate = startDate.addHours(1) // using the Datejs library

    var eventObject = {
        id: SetGreatestId(), //function that tracks the currently greatest id, also returns that value +1.  
        title: "New Event",
        editable: true, 
        start: startDate,
        end: endDate,
        color: "grey"
    }

    $(element).fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventObject, true)
}
```

The above function works fine. The event gets rendered in the expected position. The problem is when I try to modify the start date of the new event.

The problem is this: the start date of the originally clicked event always follows the start date of the new event. I have been banging my head against the wall trying to fix it to no avail.

When I drag the event upwards, the start date of the originally clicked event moves with it (the originally clicked event has editable set to false as well), and it is not meant to do this. When the new event is dragged down so that its start date exceeds the end date of the clicked event, the clicked event does something weird where it tries to render the event such that the start date comes after the end date.

This is all because the start date of the clicked event is for some reason linked to the start date of the new event.

[1] When I drag a new event within the span of the same originally clicked event, everything works fine and as expected.

*** EDIT ***

In sentence [1], what I meant was: when I use the select method to add a new event to the calendar by dragging, and that new event is being dragged within the time-span of the originally clicked event, everything works fine and as expected.

Comment: possible duplicate of [adding a click event to fullcalendar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524971/adding-a-click-event-to-fullcalendar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No expert on Date.js, but here:

```
var endDate = startDate.addHours(1) // using the Datejs library
```

Assuming that *startDate* is a plain Date object, it seems to me that *endDate* and *startDate* will reference the same date object, and that you are simply adding 1 hr to that object. You might need:

```
// Create a duplicate of startDate
var endDate = new Date(+startDate);

// Increment it by 1 hour
endDate.setHours(endDate.getHours() + 1);
```

The above doesn't use Date.js.

Comment: it didn't work :(

I also just tried removing the original clicked event, rendering the new event, and re-rendering the original clicked event afterwards. The start date of the new event was still bound to the original clicked event.

Comment: RobG you solved it, basically! 

I just made startDate a new date as well:

    var startDate = new Date(event.start)

RobG if I had the reputation to vote you up, I would.